# Is it discouraged to serially edit many of your own posts?

Tags: discussion, support

#### What I ran into

Strolling through the keys in `dconf-editor`, looking for something else, I ran into the screen's information in

```
/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/outputs
```

which showed the values:

```
['1680x1050+0+0', '1280x1024+1680+0']
```

on my system.

This surprised me a bit. I use to get this information, parsed from the output of `xrandr`.
Since [dconf](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html) is usually the preferred way to retrieve settings data, especially when used in loops, I was curious to the timing of both:

`xrandr`:

```
real    0m0.067s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

`dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/outputs:`

```
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

...which shows a *dramatic* difference.

A great part of my answers around here include a background script. In many cases I use `xrandr` in a periodical loop. In other cases I use `xrandr` only at startup of the script to "save fuel", while it would be more elegant to be able to update the information while the script is running (e.g. when an external screen is connected).

Using `dconf`instead of `xrandr`would therefore be a major improvement in many of my answers.

#### However

Editing in the "new insight" would involve many answers in my case. I wouldn't want to be suspected of abusing the system to get older posts to the front page.

My question is therefore, before flooding the site with edited older posts:

*Is it "not done" to serial- edit your own posts?*

Comment: Be sure it works, though. That command outputs nothing for me.

Comment: @muru that surprises me, I tested it from 14.04 up to 15.10 (Ubuntu "regular") . What did you test it on?

Comment: 14.04, over SSH. With `DISPLAY=:0` exported (`xrandr` works fine).

Comment: `dconf list /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/` tells me it has `vsize`, `hsize` and `active-plugins`. And I don't use Unity, though I have it installed.

Comment: @muru I will hold to edit it in then, thanks for the info!

Comment: Just do it in small enough spurts to avoid flooding the front page. 4-5 at a time, then wait ~15 minutes. There is an edit limit for your own posts, to prevent abuse.

Comment: @Seth thanks! That will most likely not be a problem. Looking at muru's comment, the edit will probably a conditional edit in the head of the script(s): *if* `/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/outputs` has a valid output *then* let the script use it in a loop instead of `xrandr`. That will take much more time to edit then mass- replacing the use of `xrandr`.

Comment: I think the problem mentioned by muru will impact the script on all systems without Unity.... Also if your linking the same scripts it may be worthwhile having them in the same place and linking them.

Comment: @Wilf as a result of muru's comment, I decided to leave it as it is, for compatibility reasons. On specifically *Unity* scripts, especially in loops, I might use the gsettings- way incidentally. The question is relevant to me however. It happened before that I came to the conclusion a *lot* of answers could be improved by a "new insight".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have nothing against you improving all of your old posts serially: *personally* I wouldn't even mind having the active questions page flooded with your edits at some point but indeed someone will do, so maybe keep the number of edits acceptable in function of the current activity (to be clearer, avoid making the active questions page become orange).

I think an edit of yours per 4-5 other posts (in average) in the active questions page would be largely acceptable by everyone.

Comment: Great line: *just avoid making the active questions tab become orange* :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I meant "page" rather than "tab". :)

Answer (score 11):

If you think an edit to your own answers would improve them, **just do it!**

Don't care about the main site.